# UILabel in UIAlertController or UITextField alike UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, uialertcontroller

I need to add some labels to `UIAlertController` and after researching it turned out that there is no normal way to do it. But as it's possible to add `UITextField`, I decided to change `UITextField`'s appearance to be alike `UILabel` (has no border and background color). But changing its background color to clear and border style to none doesn't help. How can I achieve this?
Here is the code:

```
- (void)test
{
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test Title"
                                                                    message:@"Test Message"
                                                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   //Do Some action here

                                               }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                   }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.text = @"Text: ";
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    }];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Update:**
Here is what I get:
[image: What I have]
And here is what I trying to do:
[image: What I trying to do]

Comment: Doesn't message in UIAlert behave like a label. Do you basically want a custom label in  UIAlert so that you can customise it's properties (changing font, color etc.)? Please let me know

Comment: @Chaitanya I have updated my question. There you can see what I try to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to add a custom Label in UIAlert for good UI Look.

The best way to do this either programming a custom UIView such that it feels and behaves like an UIAlertView or use one of the following libraries from github.

https://github.com/nealyoung/NYAlertViewController

https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
textField.placeholder = @"Text: ";
```

instead of

```
textField.text = @"Text: ";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this doesn't help

Comment: why you want to add labels ?

Comment: One case where I would want to add labels is when my textField has already been pre-filled with data (for instance, when providing user the option to edit information that is already there), meaning I cannot use a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of third party libs to achieve this. Just customize `UIAlertController`

```
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Table", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            
            alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
                textField.text = "No of Columns :"
                textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
                textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            
            alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
                textField.placeholder = "No of Columns"
                textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
                textField.text = "2"
                textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            
            alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
                textField.text = "No of Rows :"
                textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
                textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            
            alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
                textField.placeholder = "No of Rows"
                textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
                textField.text = "2"
            }
            let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Create", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { alert -> Void in
                let firstTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
                let secondTextField = alertController.textFields![1] as UITextField
            })
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: {
                (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in })
            
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(saveAction)

            if let textFields = alertController.textFields {
                if textFields.count > 0{
                    textFields[0].superview!.superview!.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
                    textFields[0].superview!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                }
                
                if textFields.count > 2{
                    textFields[2].superview!.superview!.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
                    textFields[2].superview!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                }
            }
            
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]